# Which site is causing my cross origin browsing error?

Tags: cors, crm, iis-8, dynamics-crm-2013

I have CRM 2013 installed and am using web resources to redirect to other web pages.

When I navigate from one of the other pages back to a page in CRM such as Contacts, it displays a blank page with just the top navigation bar. If I refresh or use the navigation bar it loads fine. After navigating a bit more an error appears:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://crm.site.com:1234" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

`https://crm.site.com:1234` is CRM.

`https://other.site.com:4321` is where the web resources redirect to.

Is the error coming from not having `https://other.site.com:4321` set up correctly to handle CORS? I have the following in Web.config:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https://crm.site.com:1234"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"/>
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Or do I need to modify something in CRM 2013 to allow this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Posting in case someone else has the same issue.

It seems that if you redirect the web resource it will cause errors. The way to do it is to add an IFrame in the web resource. Here is what my web resource ended up looking like:

```
<html>
   <body>
       <iframe src="https://other.site.com:4321"></iframe>
   </body>
</html>
```